# Angular service function being called multiple times after route change

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular8

I have an angular 8 project. It has a service function that copies data. When i copied a data and go to another page, if i come back to the same page again and copy the data again it copies data twice. If i do it again it calls service function multiple times and copies data many many times.

I tried many different ways but it still copies data multiple times. Hope you can understand what i ask. I'm waiting for your answers and solutions.

Here's my app.module.ts code;

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/compiler/src/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app';

import { CategoryComponent } from './views/category';

import { CategoryService } from './services/category';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        CategoryComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule.withConfig({ warnOnNgModelWithFormControl: 'never' }),
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/AngularProject/' }, CategoryService ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and here's my service codes;

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ICategory } from '../models/ICategory';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CategoryService {
    private linkIndex: string = "Ajax/Category/Index";
    private linkCopy: string = "Ajax/Category/Copy";

        constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    getIndex(): Observable<Array<ICategory>> {
        return this.http.get<Array<ICategory>>(this.linkIndex);
    }

    getCopy(id: string): Observable<boolean> {
        let params = new HttpParams().set("id", id);
        return this.http.get<boolean>(this.linkCopy, { params: params });
    }
}
```

and here is my CategoryComponent codes;

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { CategoryService } from "../../services/category";
import * as $ from "jquery";

@Component({
    templateUrl: './index.html'
})

export class CategoryComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    errorMsg: string;
    CategoryList: any;

    callTable: boolean;

    private subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();

    constructor(private service: CategoryService, private router: Router) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.callTable = true;
        this.FillData();
    }

    FillData() {
        if (this.callTable == true) {
            this.subscription = this.service.getIndex().subscribe((answer) => {
                this.CategoryList = answer;
                this.callTable = false;

                setTimeout(() => {
                    $(".data-table").dataTable({
                        "bJQueryUI": true,
                        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                        "sDom": '<""l>t<"F"fp>'
                    });

                    $(document).on("click", "a.cpyLink", function () {
                        $(this).addClass("active-cpy");
                        $("a.cpy-yes").attr("data-id", $(this).attr("data-id"));
                    });

                    $(document).on("click", "a.cpy-yes", () => {
                        let id: string = $("a.cpy-yes").attr("data-id");
                        this.onCopy(id);
                    });
                }, 1);
            }, resError => this.errorMsg = resError, () => { this.subscription.unsubscribe(); });
        }
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    onCopy(id) {
        this.subscription = this.service.getCopy(id).subscribe((answer) => {
            if (answer == true) {
                let currentUrl = this.router.url;
                this.router.navigate(['/'], { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => { this.router.navigate([currentUrl]) });
            }
        }, resError => this.errorMsg = resError, () => { this.subscription.unsubscribe(); });
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, every time the component is initialized, it adds a new click listener on the document. And it never removes the listener.

Comment: you're probably creating some kind of memory leak with all that jquery... get rid of it all and do things the angular way

Comment: you really mean it's because of jquery codes?

Comment: @thrashead You called onCopy(id) in FillData() and FillData() is called in ngOnInit.

Comment: should i do it like (click)=onCopy(model?.ID) on html side? This is what you mean?

Comment: So When you navigate to category page onCopy(id) is called. And `this.router.navigate(['/'], { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => { this.router.navigate([currentUrl]) });` make circle dependency of calling onCopy(id).

Comment: Yeah @thrashead you should not call onCopy(id) in ngOnInit()

Comment: but it calls the function on click. Is there a way to remove it on destroy?

Comment: Try to wrap both services (getIndex() & getCopy()) like this
`this.subscription.add( this.service.getIndex().subscribe())`
instead of
`this.subscription = this.service.getIndex().subscribe()`
Here the link to the [RxJS documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscription.js~Subscription.html).

Comment: i tried it man. it didn't work. i think this is because of calling onCopy in ngOnInit as everyone said. I need a solution to remove the click listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you should avoid mixing Angular and jQuery. Here, your specific problem is caused because you call `this.FillData()` in ngOnInit. Since ngOnInit calls every time you route to the page, the code in `this.FillData()` gets called every time you route.

Since `this.FillData()` is called repeatedly, every time you route to the page, you are attaching your event handlers in jQuery (datatable, and the onclicks) each time. Since you are never detaching the event handlers while routing away, you end up attaching the same event multiple times. This is made worse by the fact that you are attaching the handler at the Document level and using [event bubbling](https://api.jquery.com/on/), you are attaching the multiple handlers at the Document level, and each time you add a new one, it is being called an additional time.

Since you're using DataTables, I would suggest that you drop the jQuery code entirely and transition your handlers to the proper Angular approach. There are plenty of DataTables-like components out there (I've used ag-grid extensively, for example).

If you **must** use jQuery (for whatever reason), then you need to refactor your code to either remove any existing event handlers when routing to/from the component. Pretty sure you could just stick an `.off('click')` in there.

`$(document).off("click", "a.cpy-yes").on("click", "a.cpy-yes"....`

Or you need to ensure that you only attach the event handlers **once** in the parent component (since you're bubbling it down anyways).

Comment: thanks for your answes. how can i remove the handlers? is tehre a way?

Comment: Edited the answer, you should be able to just insert an off in there before the on.

Comment: you're the man. you saved my life thanks man. I added $(document).off("click", "a.cpyLink"); $(document).off("click", "a.cpy-yes"); codes in onCopy() function before i called the service and it's done. thanks again :)